# Load a page, give a variable on alert of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a intranet-website here that checks if an employee has used the form correctly and (via php) calls then a JavaScript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error!"); history.back(-1);</script>
```

Now, there is a php-variable with a huge amount of text. how can I call the site and give the variable with it, instead of using a simple history.back, where every variables are deleted instantly? Someone an idea how to make this without jQuery?

Comment: you are sending variable with url or what ? Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error!"); location.href="page.php?yourvar=<?php echo $var; ?>";</script>
```

This will show the alert box and then redirect user to "page.php", where you can get your variable value using `$_GET['yourvar']`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not entirely sure what you mean but you could try something like this?:

```
if ($error) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert('.$error.');</script>';
    header('Location: page.php?var='.$myVar);
}
```

They should still get alerted with the error and then get sent back to the previous page, if this is what you were asking.

Comment: erm no. sorry, maybe i was not precise enough. I meant something like: echo "<script type="text/javascript">alert('.$error.'); window.load(http://blabla.php?".$myVar.");";

Comment: maybe a good answer in common, but I can't use headers, long story... but thanks for the try.